# Display the text inside the background color

Tags: html, css

we have page looking like this: [link](http://stylebaby.com/career)

we need some changes as below:

means `HOME PAGE > CAREER` should display inside the background-color-white ,

`Required Fields` should display in left

`Submit Cv` button should come at middle

**css**

```
<style type="text/css">
.career-page-box{
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
background: #fff;
}
.career-page-box .page-title {
margin: 10px 0 0px 0;
padding: 0;
clear: both;
}
.career-page-box .page-title h1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 8px 0;
text-align:center;
}
.career-page-box .fill-out {
border-bottom: #ddd solid 1px;
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
text-align: center;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel {
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .required {
margin: 10px 0 8px;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group {
clear: both;
width: 49.8%;
margin:auto;
text-align:left;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group label{
text-align:left !important;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group .form-list li {
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group .form-list li label {
line-height: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group .form-list li label em {
color: #df280a;
margin: 0 0 0 2px;
font-style: normal;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group .custom-select {
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0px 0 0;
background-position: 98% 50%;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group .custom-select select {
margin-top: 0;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .buttons-set {
clear:both;
border-top: 0;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel .buttons-set button.button {

}

.custom-select {
border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
width: 120px;
height: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #fff url("../images/custom-select-downarrow.png") no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
.arrow-up {
background: transparent url("../images/arrow-up-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 15px;
width: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
top: -15px;
}
.custom-select select {
padding: 5px 8px!important;
width: 100%;
border: none;
box-shadow: none;
background: transparent;
background-image: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}
input[type=email],
input[type=search],
input[type=number],
input[type=password],
input[type=tel],
input[type=text] {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
input[type=email],
input[type=search],
input[type=number],
input[type=password],
input[type=tel],
input[type=text] {
height: 32px;
padding: 0 8px;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
background: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 13px;
}
.careercv
{
padding-top: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
{
.buttons-set {
text-align: center !important;
}
}
</style>
```

**html**

```
<div class="career-page-box">
  <div class="page-title career-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Career') ?></h1>
  </div>
  <?php $careerForm=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormData();?>
  <form action="<?php echo mage::getUrl('career/index/save'); ?>" id="carrer_form" method="post" name="carrer_form" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="fill-out"><?php echo $this->__('Please fill out the following information.') ?></div>
    <div class="form-panel">
      <div class="inner-panel">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Required Fields') ?><em>*</em></p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
              <label for="jobtitle"><?php echo $this->__('How did you hear about us') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <div class="custom-select">
                <select name="jobtitle" id="jobtitle" class="validate-select form-control required-entry">
                  <option value="">Please Select</option>
                  <option value="NewsPaper" <?php if($careerForm['jobtitle']=="NewsPaper"){
              ?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>NewsPaper</option>
                  <option value="onlinsite" <?php if($careerForm['jobtitle']=="onlinsite"){?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Online Website</option>
                  <option value="Friends" <?php if($careerForm['jobtitle']=="Friends"){?>selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Friends</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="jobtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Job Type') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <?php  $jobs=Mage::getStoreConfig('career/career/job_list');
           if($jobs!='')
           $jobsselected=explode(",",$jobs);
         else
          $jobsselected='';

           ?>
              <div class="custom-select">
                <select name="job" id="job" class="form-control required-entry">
                  <option value=""> Please Select </option>
                  <?php foreach($jobsselected as $jobs): ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $jobs ?>"> <?php echo $jobs; ?> </option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
              <label for="firstname"><?php echo $this->__('First Name') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <input name="fname" class="form-control required-entry"  size="45" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('') ?>" value="<?php echo $careerForm['fname'];?>"/>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="lastname"><?php echo $this->__('Last Name') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <input name="lname" class="form-control required-entry"  size="45" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('') ?>" value="<?php echo $careerForm['lname'];?>"/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
              <label for="emailaddress"><?php echo $this->__('Email address') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <input name="email_address" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('') ?>" class="form-control required-entry validate-email" type="text" value="<?php echo $careerForm['email_address'];?>"/>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
              <label for="telephonenumber"><?php echo $this->__('Telephone Number') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <input name="phone" class="form-control required-entry validate-number" type="text" value="<?php echo $careerForm['phone'];?>" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <ul class="form-list">
            <li>
              <label for="cv"><?php echo $this->__('Upload Your Cv') ?><em>*</em></label>
              <input name="cv" class="form-control required-file careercv" type="file" />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-set">
          <button class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit Your Cv'); ?>" type="submit"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit Cv') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
   var carrerForm = new VarienForm('carrer_form', true);
//]]>
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set your container `form-panel` a `max-width` for example a `500px` then put a `text-align:left` to `.required` then for your `form-group` set the `width:100%`then for the `button` remove the `float:right`

CSS edited:

```
.main{
   background: #fff;
   padding: 20px;
}
.career-page-box .form-panel {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

.career-page-box .form-panel .required {
    margin: 10px 0 8px;
    text-align: left;
}

.career-page-box .form-panel .form-group {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.buttons-set button.button {
    margin-left: 5px;
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: please help me to display `submit cv button` at middle

Comment: as you can see for this class `.buttons-set button.button` I remove the `float:right`. Just remove it and it will be fine

Comment: i added `float:right;` for `.buttons-set button.button` but it did't worked for me.

Comment: no, remove `float:right` as you can see in my sample `float:right` was removed

Comment: sorry, i didt added any `float:right` code in the page

Comment: Okay just add this `.buttons-set button.button{float:none;}` to it and everything will work fine. You can accept my answer if it fixed your problem. Cheers

Comment: i want to delete line present below  text `Please fill out the following information.`

Comment: no, not yet, line which is presetn below this text : `Please fill out the following information`

Comment: Give me the link I can't access the old link

Answer (score 1):

Add White background to your main div and remove the top margin for breadcrumbs like this:

```
.main{
   background: #fff;
   padding: 20px;
}

.breadcrumbs {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `breadcrumbs` div under the `career-page-box` and make some change in your css like below

css -

```
.career-page-box {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative; /*add this*/
    width: 90%;
}
```

and

```
.breadcrumbs {
    left: 10px;/*add this*/
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;/*add this*/
    top: 10px;/*add this*/
}
```

I hope I'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your support.